# Does <pre> fit in AMP? What if use <amp-fit> instead of <pre>?

Tags: web

I am changing my website code to complete AMP design, as we know there are variously limited specifies tags in AMP, so here I am confused with the  tag. It works fine on local output. I am confused by this tag using in  AMP. Is there any other tag to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to use the [online amp-validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/). It will point out if you are violating any AMP specific rules. If you are running your page on a server (either local / remote), you can perform amp-validation by appending `#development=1` at the end of your url in your browser.  This will display the validation log on your browser console.

Read more here : [validating amp pages](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/validate)

Comment: I did so, and I am getting errors, but it states -"Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." and tells failed to load and also shows "Fetching file for validation failed". I think I am not writing code to get it validate. can you please help me with it. Thanks

Comment: Could you share your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/)?